# Unanble to produce the plot using ctree(partykit)

Tags: r, ctree

I am trying to plot a simple conditional inference tree using the "partykit" package in R. But when I try to produce the plot of the ctree, it produces the following error -

> Error in valid.viewport(x, y, width, height, just, gp, clip, mask, xscale,  :
> invalid 'yscale' in viewport

I am attaching the code that I have used and also the plot that I am getting -

```
library(partykit)
data("airquality")


dumm_model = ctree(Ozone ~ ., data=airquality, na.action = na.pass,
                   control = ctree_control(teststat = "quadratic", testtype = "Bonferroni"))

plot(dumm_model)
```

[image: Ctree plot produced with no terminal nodes]

The dataset "airquality" obviously has some missing values, but I used the na.pass value in the na.action argument which is supposed to ignore the missing values in the dataset. Can someone help me with this problem of getting the plot of the tree?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the NA's use `na.action = na.omit`

```
dumm_model2 = ctree(Ozone ~ ., data=airquality, na.action = na.omit,
            control = ctree_control(teststat = "quadratic", 
            testtype = "Bonferroni"))
plot(dumm_model2)
```

[image: Tree diagram]

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my question is what if there are NA values in my dataset and I want to use them as a part of my analysis? How could I have used the ctree function?